# Css queries isn't making things responsive?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make this small website responsive, but for some reason whenever I use media queries to set max and min width of a device it doesn't seem to follow it, what I mean is if I set a responsive design for iphone 5, then it will be for iphone 5 temporary, if i then try to do responsive design for Ipad, then the iphone 5 is ignored and now it follows Ipad's responsive design, can someone please help? here is my code(syntax... although its not a programming language lol :P

**Source Code**

```
/*Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 320px)
and (max-width : 480px) {

    h1{
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    h2{
        transform: translateX(40%);
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    h3{
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom:15px;
    }
    input[type=submit] {
        width: 250px; 
        transform: translateX(10%);
    }
    .relocate{margin-top: -55px;}

    .form .email{
    width: 275px;
    transform: translateX(8%);
    }
    .form select{
        width: 275px;
        transform: translateX(8%);
    }
}



/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px){

    h1{
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    h2{
        transform: translateX(47%);
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    h3{
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom:15px;
    }
    input[type=submit] {
        width: 650px; 
        transform: translateX(10%);
    }
    .relocate{margin-top: -55px;}

    .form .email{
    width: 345px;
    transform: translateX(8%);
    }
    .form select{
        width: 325px;
        transform: translateX(8%);
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px){

    h1{
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    h2{
        transform: translateX(49%);
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    h3{
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom:15px;
    }
    input[type=submit] {
        width: 800px; 
        transform: translateX(10%);
    }
    .relocate{margin-top: -55px;}

    .form .email{
    width: 460px;
    transform: translateX(8%);
    }
    .form select{
        width: 450px;
        transform: translateX(8%);
    }


}



/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 1025px)
and (max-device-width : 1140px){

    h1{
        font-size: 29px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    h2{
        transform: translateX(49%);
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    h3{
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom:15px;
    }
    input[type=submit] {
        width: 800px; 
        transform: translateX(10%);
    }
    .relocate{margin-top: -55px;}

    .form .email{
    width: 460px;
    transform: translateX(8%);
    }
    .form select{
        width: 450px;
        transform: translateX(8%);
    }
}



/* iPhone 5 (portrait &amp; landscape)----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 568px) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}

/* iPhone 5 (landscape)----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 568px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}

/* iPhone 5 (portrait)----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 568px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* STYLES GO HERE */
}
```

Comment: Don't code for devices. Start with the smallest viewport and slowly work your way up to a desktop viewport, adding breakpoints for various page content etc. where needed.

Comment: I'm on that path but it just doesn't work for somereason like if u look above I started with 320 and 480, then 768 and 1024....

Comment: why when I did 768 and 1024, it ignored the 320 and 480 and then it didn't become responsive ?

Comment: Don't use `min-device-width` or `max-device-width`, they're the wrong measurement for what you want (and they're deprecated). You want to target viewport widths. Also, it might help to [learn about what a CSS pixel is](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html).

Comment: oh I dunno how I had those I always use max-width and nothing else besides that. I changed them but still didn't work, I'm really struggling with this, I spent hours trying to just make the header part responsive

Comment: Use `min-width` as your base. Start small and work up. To get any real input you'll need to provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now we can only take a shot in the dark.

Comment: OKay now i'm confused, it works but when i refresh, it starts with the smallest width first? ah this is so hard to keep track of the newer responsive design..

Comment: It should be relatively simple. Start with the smallest viewport styles (**no media queries at all because this is the default!**). Then work your way up to larger viewports. Start with common breakpoints (i.e. 480, 576, 768, 992, 1200) and fill in layout bugs where needed between those sizes. The objective is to create a fluid design that will work on any device. Rather than design to each device. There will be exceptions to this, though rarely.

Comment: OMGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG I love you <3 i was doing it in any order. I  wana kill my self now :( i spent hours ...... omg

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

as a meta tag of your html website.

Without this meta tag the mobile browser doesn't know that the website is responsible and enters in a compatibility mode and this way the website doesn't follow media queries.

Comment: I did it have it the entire time, but re-copied it and pasted it, still didn't make difference :(